# Liquibase migration files in spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, migration, refactoring, liquibase

I have a spring boot application that uses liquibase for database/data migration, the current state is, there is one migration file which is `db.changelog-master.xml`, that contains all the changesets. Now I want to divide this file into multiple files, or at least, the created new scripts will be created in new files. So I tried to add `db.changelog-master.yaml` to include the main file and any additional files. But the thing is, it generates a new checksum value so the scripts that already on the old file execute again. Is there any way to separate the old big file or even include it in the `db.changelog-master.yaml` without running the old scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible options can be :

**1.Change the logicalFilePath:**

Liquibase allows you to define so called logical file path of your changelog. This allows you to fake Liquibase that the changesets actually come from the same file. Liquibase will treat the changeset as if it was previously defined in changelog.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog dbchangelog-3.5.xsd"
                   logicalFilePath="classpath:changelog.xml">

    <changeSet author="me" id="changeset2">
        <createTable tableName="TABLE2">
            <column name="COLUMN1" type="VARCHAR2(10)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

This approach is not the best if your intent to split the changelog is to move the part of it to another package, module, and so on.

**2.Use intermediate changelog:**

The first step is to move all the relevant changesets to another file elsewhere. We need to fake Liquibase that those changesets didn't change. We do it by modifying the FILENAME value in the database as part of the Liquibase changelog itself .

Create one more (intermediate/temporary) changelog (let's call it tmp-migration.xml) with just this one changeset:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

    <changeSet id="moving changesets from changelog to changelog2" author="Maros Kovacme">
        <sql>
            UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG
            SET
            FILENAME = REPLACE(FILENAME, 'changelog.xml', 'changelog2.xml'))
            WHERE
            ID IN (
            'changeset2'
            );
        </sql>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

This changeset will replace the FILENAME column value in the DB from classpath:changelog.xml to classpath:changelog2.xml. When we then run Liquibase with the changelog2.xml, it will think that all changesets are already applied.

The last step we have to apply is to define the corresponding beans in our context in the right order:

```
@Configuration
public class MultipleLiquiaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibaseChangelog(DataSource dataSource) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:changelog.xml");

        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("liquibaseChangelog")
    public SpringLiquibase liquibaseMigration(DataSource dataSource) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:tmp-migration.xml");

        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean("liquibase")
    @DependsOn("liquibaseMigration")
    public SpringLiquibase liquibaseChangelog2(DataSource dataSource) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:changelog2.xml");

        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

Details [here](https://dev.to/vladonemo/splitting-liquibase-changelong-no-problem-2a4l)